# What are some applications of 2 stack pushdown automata?

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata, applied-theory

What are some real world application for 2 stack pushdown automata, as i can only find pushdown automata applications in the internet

Comment: Looking for real-world applications of purely theoretical concepts can often turn out to be a fool's quest.

Comment: Recall that [two-stack PDAs are equivalent in power to TMs](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/3162/98), so there are many equivalent models to choose from.