# Can a two-stack PDA accept language $a^nb^mc^nd^m$ which is not context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, machine-models

Can a two-stack PDA accept language $L=\{a^nb^mc^nd^m \mid n \geq m\}$, which has no context-free grammar?

I don't believe this has a context-free grammar, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: See [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/is-a-push-down-automaton-with-two-stacks-equivalent-to-a-turing-machine) for the power of two-stack PDA, and [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free) for techniques to show that the language is not context-free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A two-stack PDA is equivalent in computing power to a Turing machine. Since a Turing machine can accept that language (stated without proof), a two-stack PDA can as well. The actual definition of such a machine is left as an exercise :)

Comment: Thanks!
P.S. What did you mean about _stated without proof_ ? Are there languages which a turing machines can't accept?

Comment: @echadromani a valid program that never finishes under some input (look up the halting problem for more input)

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to know about the equivalence to a Turing Machine to decide this language and if it was the intention of this exercise to come up with the equivalence, the language is (IMHO) to easy to motivate this.

A simple two-stack PDA for this language works like this:

1. Put $n$ on both counters, while counting $a$s.
2. Use counter one to check the $b$s.
3. Count up on counter one and down on counter two to check the $c$s.
4. Check the $d$s.

I left out some details, but filling them should be easy.

By the way: You should not **believe** that this language is not context free, but **prove** it (it should be obvious which word to choose as a counter example using the pumping lemma).

Comment: I don't think it's context free, I think it's easy to prove that it's **not** context free, therefore I ask you not to believe, but to prove.

Comment: No need for that, problem requires me to draw 2-Stack PDA for that

Comment: Well, you should not hand in the proof, just make sure you understand that this can't be context free.