# Can a queue automaton recognize palindromes?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, automata, queues

Consider the language of even-length palindromes $L = \{ WW^R \mid W \in \{0,1\}^* \}$. This language is surely context free and I need an NPDA to recognize it.

But, what if we replace the stack with a queue which supports insert and delete operations? Can a queue automaton accept $L$?

Comment: Your question was so badly phrased it made no sense at all. I edited into a form that be answered.

Comment: [Closely related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21460/prove-queue-automaton-is-equivalent-to-turing-machine). [Almost duplicate](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35831/l-x-xr-mid-x-in-0-1-not-accepted-by-a-queue-automaton).

Comment: And [How can one simulate a PDA with a FIFO queue PDA?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7003/how-can-one-simulate-a-pda-with-a-fifo-queue-pda) seems relevant to.

Answer (score 9):

The construction of a PDA except with a FIFO instead of a LIFO data structure attached can mimic any single tape TM as follows: it keeps the cell contents in the queue along with two special markers for the end of the tape and for the head of the TM. Every time you make a move, you just go through the entire queue and re-push everything you pop, making whatever slight modification in head position and tape contents you require.

So this is computationally equivalent to a Turing Machine, so in particular it can recognize $L = \{ww^R \mid w \in \{0, 1\}^*\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Can you elaborate more on the part how it mimics TM ?

Comment: One more query - what if the language was  L = { WW | W belongs to (0,1)* } ?

Comment: @Willturner I Think filling in the details will be a good exercise. As per the second question, the answer is of course yes -- we can easily design a TM (with multiple tapes perhaps to make it even easier; $k$-tape TMs and single-tape TMs define the same class of languages) that accepts $L$.

Comment: Okk , I'll see that in detail. Just a doubt - Is it ok, to say that queue automaton recognizes this language and hence it is Recursively enumerable language and not CFL, which it was before when we used stack?

Comment: @Willturner Please stop vampiring. You've been warned before. Take the answers to get, absorb them, think on them. If you encounter new questions, do your own research, and possible post a new question. Don't pester answerers in the comments!

Comment: " Is it ok, to say that queue automaton recognizes this language and hence it is Recursively enumerable language and not CFL, which it was before when we used stack? " -- no, not at all. The definition of CFL does not change just because you investigate some other machine model.