# Is the Shakespeare Programming Language Turing complete?

Tags: turing-machines, programming-languages

I was reading about tge Turing machine. I also came across with [the `Shakespeare` programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare_Programming_Language). After trying to understand the basics of the PL, I thought that it must be non-Turing complete. On some [page](https://artificialcognition.github.io/playing-with-shakespeare-programming-language-spl) I found out that I was wrong and `Shakespeare` is actually "turing complete".

I didn't find how can I create while loops or recursive calls in `Shakespeare` so I can't understand why it us Turing complete.

Will be glad for some explanation.

Comment: Have you seen: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/is-a-push-down-automaton-with-two-stacks-equivalent-to-a-turing-machine ? In given language you declare number of stacks to use, two will suffice. There are conditionals and goto instructions, so there are loops.

Comment: Loops in Shakespeare can be created with [gotos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare_Programming_Language#Conditional_statements_and_gotos).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that page, the snippet

```
Juliet:
 Am I better than you?

Hamlet:
 If so, let us proceed to scene III.
```

essentially means

```
if (Juliet > Hamlet) goto Scene III
```

This can be used to implement `while` loops. In pseudo syntax:

```
Scene II:
if (Juliet > Hamlet) goto Scene III
... some statements here
goto Scene II
Scene III:
... more statements here
```

is essentially equivalent to

```
while (Juliet <= Hamlet) {
   ... some statements here
}
... more statements here
```